# Reset jQuery Scroll to anchor if user scrolls back to top on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I currently have a search bar for jobs on my website. The jobs are loaded by ajax and to make this more mobile friendly, it will scroll to an anchor point on the page on any device where the screen size is less than 500px.

This works fine, however if the user the scrolls back up to the search inputs and try's a new search, the results load but it will not scroll again to the anchor.

Here is my code:

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
 function scrollToAnchor(aid){
 var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#search-but").click(function() {
  scrollToAnchor('job-start');
});
};
```

What can I do to enable the functionality I require please?

Comment: Is the `#search-but` dynamically created when trying a new search?

Comment: It's not dynamically created no, just the results

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Im not getting any errors no.

Comment: Actually I do see an error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined